# How to plot pandas timestamps.Timestamp or datetime.time in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, series

I have the following format of data:

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

It contains data as follows:

```
0        2020-06-30 14:00:37.366000-04:00
1        2020-06-30 14:00:37.400000-04:00
```

If I try to plot it using matplotlib, it gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Timestamp'
```

Also, if I convert the dataframe to extract only time information as follows:

```
df.datetime.time
```

I get the following type:

```
datetime.time
```

When I try to plot it, I get the same attribute error as above. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please post the full traceback, including the code that actually gives you the `AttributeError`

Comment: Here is the full traceback: 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Timestamp'

Comment: The actual code:  time_converted = pd.to_datetime(Date_time.Timestamp);

time = time_converted.dt.time;    plt.plot_date(time, value)
plt.show()

Comment: tried `pd.to_datetime(Date_time)`? - if it not already is a series of dtype datetime...

Comment: you are right, I mistakenly put Date_time.TImestamp. It's working now. Thank you